# SSIS Extraction/ DTSX

Tags: sql, ssis

I got this amazing code here on Stack but it was 8 years ago but works perfectly but, when run the t-script the column ObjectName always is NULL, someone can help me to fix it if possible?

The SQL Script

```sql
SELECT Pkg.props.value('../../DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="ObjectName"]
[1]','varchar(MAX)') ObjectName, 
Pkg.props.value('(@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 
SqlStatement FROM (select cast(pkgblob.BulkColumn as XML) pkgXML from 
openrowset(bulk '\\MYDTS.dtsx',single_blob) 
as pkgblob) t CROSS APPLY pkgXML.nodes('//DTS:ObjectData//SQLTask:SqlTaskData') Pkg(props) 
  UNION 
SELECT Pkg.props.value('../../../../DTS:Property[@DTS:Name="ObjectName"]
[1]','varchar(MAX)') ObjectName, 
Pkg.props.value('data(./properties/property[@name=''SqlCommand''])[1]', 
'varchar(max)') SqlStatement FROM(select cast(pkgblob.BulkColumn as XML) 
 pkgXML from openrowset(bulk '\\MYDTS.dtsx',single_blob) as 
 pkgblob) t CROSS APPLY 
 pkgXML.nodes('//DTS:Executable//pipeline//components//component') Pkg(props) 
WHERE Pkg.props.value('data(./properties/property[@name=''SqlCommand''])
[1]', 'varchar(max)') <>''
```

And the result has been attached below. I would like to show the ObjectName instead NULL and I don't know how I can fix it.

[image: ImageResult]

Answer (score 1):

ObjectName is no longer what/where it use to be from those years ago.

You'll need to browse the current dtsx in XML form and find your equivalent ObjectName.

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\PathToPackage\MYDTS.dtsx', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

My sample dtsx looks like this in XML form:

```xml
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts" DTS:refId="Package" DTS:CreationDate="7/23/2019 7:23:29 AM" DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package" DTS:CreatorComputerName="Overflow" DTS:CreatorName="Overflow\Stack" DTS:DTSID="{DEED1FFC-FCE3-4C63-A90C-3382EDA388A1}" DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package" DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="14.0.3002.113" DTS:LocaleID="1033" DTS:ObjectName="deduplicate" DTS:PackageType="5" DTS:VersionBuild="20" DTS:VersionGUID="{27B38889-4D80-45F6-9CB0-F6B430B1DBBE}">
  <DTS:Property DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
  <DTS:Variables />
  <DTS:Executables>
    <DTS:Executable DTS:refId="Package\Execute SQL Task" DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.ExecuteSQLTask" DTS:Description="Execute SQL Task" DTS:DTSID="{A6053AE9-7445-4973-9AFD-E3AFFE97B68F}" DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.ExecuteSQLTask" DTS:LocaleID="-1" DTS:ObjectName="Execute SQL Task" DTS:TaskContact="Execute SQL Task; Microsoft Corporation; SQL Server 2017 RC1; © 2017 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1" DTS:ThreadHint="1">
      <DTS:Variables />
      <DTS:ObjectData>
        <SQLTask:SqlTaskData xmlns:SQLTask="www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask" SQLTask:SqlStatementSource="Select GetDate()" />
      </DTS:ObjectData>
    </DTS:Executable>
...
```

In this specific XML, the next todos:

- Pull out everything that is a SqlTaskData
- Retrieve the SqlStatementSource value
- Walk up two levels "../../" to DTS:Executable and Retrieve the ObjectName Attribute

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
    'www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS DTS,
    'www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask' AS SQLTask
), 
dtsxAsXML AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\PathToPackage\MYDTS.dtsx', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
SELECT 
    X.Y.value('(../../@DTS:ObjectName)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ObjectName,
    X.Y.value('(@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS SqlStatementSource 
FROM dtsxAsXML d
CROSS APPLY d.BulkColumn.nodes('//DTS:ObjectData//SQLTask:SqlTaskData') X(Y)
```

| ObjectName | SqlStatementSource |
| --- | --- |
| Execute SQL Task | Select GetDate() |

Repeat this process for the dataflow component, the bottom union in your example.

Since you're already getting your SQL Statements, you don't need to use these example queries, you just need to review the xml from your dtsx, then find and change the relative paths in your existing query to the value you want.

Comment: Hello there, thank you so much I will try it... again, thanks a lot